# Sharing opengl rendering between two apps

Tags: c#, c++, opengl, rendering, directshow

I have an c++ app which performs some OpenGL rendering to framebuffer, then draws it on GUI. Also I have an virtual camera based on directshow filter, written on C#. I want to find robust and performance way to share OpenGL rendering output with a directshow virtual camera.

Comment: The extension [`WGL_NV_DX_interop2`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/NV/DX_interop2.txt) might be helpful. I have never tried it in two different processes, but the operating system feature it is based on (WDDM share handles) works across processes.

Comment: What is your exact directshow pipeline? In the general case, the source filters generate media samples and deliver them downstream. In what way you want to share the output of your renderer with the virtual camera?